# Root view controller always set as tableViewController when Navigation Controller is set

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, uistoryboard

When I use storyboards and drag out a navigation controller from the object library in Interface Builder, the root view controller, which comes with the nav controller, is always a table view controller.

Most of the time, I would just like a simple view controller. Is there a way to drag out the navigation controller and have a simple view controller set as the default, instead of the table view controller I'm getting now?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

The navigation controller usually comes connected to another controller which is the root controller. You can always delete the segue and table view controller, drag out a View Controller and reconnect the segue with a control click using the rootViewController option.